# File downloading in php after displaying some text

Tags: php, header, download

Hi I need to create file downloading. the fill up form for download and form validation and dB inserting all are in the same page. if the form is submitted then file downloading needs to be automatically triggered with save as window. I wrote the code as:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$u=$_POST['uname'];
/*similarly getting all posted data*/
echo '<br><b>'.JText::_( 'Thank you for submitting your details...' ).'</b>';
 $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
  $query = "/*db inserting query*/";
  $db->setQuery( $query );
  $db->query();

  $filee=  basename($path); /*$path contains value form $_POST*/
   $full='http://localhost/joomla/images/uploads/'.$filee;

  ?>
 <br><b>
  <span>If the download  does not start automatically in a few seconds, <a href="<?php     echo JURI::base(); ?>/images/myfile/<?php echo $filee;?>" target="_blank"><b> Click this link</b></a></span></b>


 <?php


   header('Content-Description:File Transfer');
   header("Content-type:application/pdf");
   header("Content-type:application/zip");
   header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
   header("Content-type:image/png");
   header("Content-type:application/msword");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filee."");
   header("Cache-control: private");
   readfile($full);


   }
 else{ code for printing fill up form}
```

I need to print the "thanks for submitting.."..etc message before downloading.but now when I submit the fill up form download starts with out displaying the above text. what should I do for making download after waiting some time?

Comment: use `sleep();` to wait for sometime

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sleep()` in php to delay the execution.So try like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$u=$_POST['uname'];
echo '<br><b>'.JText::_( 'Thank you for submitting your details...' ).'</b>';
 $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
  $query = "/*db inserting query*/";
  $db->setQuery( $query );
  $db->query();
  $filee=  basename($path); /*$path contains value form $_POST*/
  $full='http://localhost/joomla/images/uploads/'.$filee;

  ?>
 <br><b>
  <span>If the download  does not start automatically in a few seconds, <a href="<?php     echo JURI::base(); ?>/images/myfile/<?php echo $filee;?>" target="_blank"><b> Click this link</b></a></span></b>


 <?php

   sleep(10);//Will delay for 10 seconds

   header('Content-Description:File Transfer');
   header("Content-type:application/pdf");
   header("Content-type:application/zip");
   header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
   header("Content-type:image/png");
   header("Content-type:application/msword");
   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filee."");
   header("Cache-control: private");
   readfile($full);


   }
 else{ code for printing fill up form}
```

Comment: i tried that.but sleeps before printing the text"thanks for submitting.." and starts downloading. i need to start downloading after displaying those messages in the page.